# Visual Studio 2015 Notifications

Tags: layout, visual-studio-2015, ide

I slipped my hand with the mouse and managed to drag the list of notifications that pulls down from the flag icon next to the feedback icon outside the menu, so that it now appears as its own window.

[image: Escaped Notifications menu]

How do I put it back under the flag?

Answer (score 1):

From the main menu select **Window** - **Reset Window Layout** or just click and drag the title bar of the Notifications window to the original location. See [Customizing window layouts in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx) for more details.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it appears resetting the windows puts notifications in the same area of the IDE as Solution Explorer, and not under the flag. Going to see if I can glean anything from VS 2013's installation settings that could help me here.

Comment: I've added screenshots with the default Notifications window position. This is the same place it goes after Reset Window Layout on my machine.